# SQL: Don't show duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to *not* show duplicate rows in output for the sql below and so I have 'distinct' in there, but this doesn't work. I get output like:

```
PermitNumber PermitName CreatedOn  
111          ABCD       1/2/2011  
111          ABCD       3/4/2012  
222          DFES       3/6/2000
```

and I want only one row with 111 but I get more than 1 row because 111 has more than one modification, but I don't care if it has 1 or 1000.

```
select  distinct (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), 
        dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId),
    mod.[CreatedOn] as [CreatedOn]
from    tblPermit mp, dbo.[tblModification] mod
where mod.PermitId = mp.PermitId
order by 1
```

Using SQL Server

Comment: 'distinct' does not apply just to a single column but to all the columns specified in the select clause. In your case CreatedOn is different for the two rows with PermitNumber 111. Hence both the rows appears in the output. If the CreatedOn were same for both the rows, then only 1 row would have appear in the output for PermitNumber 111.

Comment: with `dbo.` looks like sql server to me

Comment: First things first. Why do you select created_on if you don't care about it? Also as said before, the "distinct" applies to the set of ALL  columns queried on, so it doesn't care about your brackets

Comment: >>Why do you select created_on? Because I do want to see it

Comment: @numberwang I am slow so here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71068/3) ;)

Comment: @numberwang which created_on do you want then? Is it the first or most recent or any random one? You will have to specify this otherwise you will get a distinct row for each one that has a different created_on date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Distinct applies to all columns so you could use an aggregate function:

```
  select  mp.PermitNumber,
    mp.PermitName,
    max(mod.[CreatedOn])as [CreatedOn]
  from    tblPermit mp
  Inner join dbo.[tblModification] mod
      on mod.PermitId = mp.PermitId
  Group by mp.PermitNumber,
    mp.PermitName
  order by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` (exact syntax depending on your dbms):

```
select  (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), 
    dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId),
min(mod.[CreatedOn] as [CreatedOn])
from    tblPermit mp, dbo.[tblModification] mod
where mod.PermitId = mp.PermitId
group by (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH latestRecord
AS
(
    SELECT  PermitNumber, PermitName, CreatedOn,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PermitNumber, PermitName
                                ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC) rn
    FROM    tblPermit
)
SELECT PermitNumber, PermitName, CreatedOn
FROM    latestRecord
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: [is this just useful or brilliant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148066/can-i-search-my-comments-using-some-keywords)? In a quest of getting a great feature :)

Answer (score 2):

Than you should decide how to deal with a creation date. For example to show maximum of these days.
Distinct is applied to all fields in the select clause.

```
select  distinct (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), 
        dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId)
from    tblPermit mp, dbo.[tblModification] mod
where mod.PermitId = mp.PermitId
order by 1
```

This will work but without created date

Answer (score 1):

based on the limited info in the question try:

```
select  distinct (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), 
        dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId),
    MIN(mod.[CreatedOn]) as [CreatedOn]
  --^^^new
from    tblPermit mp, dbo.[tblModification] mod
where mod.PermitId = mp.PermitId
group by (dbo.PermitNumber(mp.PermitId)), ---<<new
        dbo.PermitName(mp.PermitId),      ---<<new
order by 1
```

you need to do something with all the `mod.[CreatedOn])` values for each row, so group them together and display the MIN of each.