# Find Duplicates in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates

I have a table called `FLOORS` which contains a many duplicate values

```
FLOORCODE   FLOORDESC
00          Ground Floor
01          1st Floor
02          2nd Floor
00          Ground Floor
00          NEW Floor
```

What code do I need for a query that will only bring back values where the same `FLOORCODE` has been used but with a different `FLOORDESC`. 
So in the above example I only want to see

```
FLOORCODE     FLOORDESC
00            Ground Floor
00            NEW Floor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Don't show duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219319/sql-dont-show-duplicates)

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    FLOORCODE CHAR(2),
    FLOORDESC VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    ('00', 'Ground Floor'),
    ('01', '1st Floor'),
    ('02', '2nd Floor'),
    ('00', 'Ground Floor'),
    ('00', 'NEW Floor')

SELECT DISTINCT t2.FLOORCODE, t2.FLOORDESC
FROM (
    SELECT FLOORCODE
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY FLOORCODE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FLOORDESC) > 1
) t
JOIN @t t2 ON t.FLOORCODE = t2.FLOORCODE
```

result -

```
FLOORCODE FLOORDESC
--------- ----------------
00        Ground Floor
00        NEW Floor
```

Comment: Fantastic, works treat. Thank you for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using window functions:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*, min(floordesc) over (partition by floorcode) as minfd,
             max(floordesc) over (partition by floorcode) as maxfd
      from floors f
     ) f
where minfd <> maxfd;
```

An alternative that doesn't use window functions might use `exists`:

```
select f.*
from floors f
where exists (select 1
              from floors f2
              where f2.floorcode = f.floorcode and f2.floordesc <> f.floordesc
             );
```

Note that both of these can benefit from an index on `floors(floorcode, floordesc)`.  And both these versions ignore NULL values, although that is easily incorporated into the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause to find the offending `floorcode`, and then an `in` clause to find the actual rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT floorcode, floordesc
FROM   floors
WHERE  floorcode IN (SELECT   floorcode
                     FROM     floors
                     GROUP BY floorcode
                     HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT floordesc) > 1)
```

Comment: This will bring `00, Ground Floor` twice.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas good point, thanks, should have a `distinct` there. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using windowed count as well:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    FLOORCODE VARCHAR(50),
    FLOORDESC VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Test (FLOORCODE, FLOORDESC)
VALUES ('00', 'Ground Floor')
    , ('01', '1st Floor')
    , ('02', '2nd Floor')
    , ('00', 'Ground Floor')
    , ('00', 'NEW Floor');

SELECT DISTINCT FLOORCODE, FLOORDESC
FROM (
    SELECT FLOORCODE, FLOORDESC, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY FLOORCODE) AS Cnt
    FROM @Test
    ) AS T
WHERE T.Cnt > 1;
```

#### Result:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ FLOORCODE ║  FLOORDESC   ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║        00 ║ Ground Floor ║
║        00 ║ NEW Floor    ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do it

```
select floorcode, floordesc
from yourtable where floorcode in 
( select floorcode 
  from yourtable
  group by floorcode having count(*) >1 )
```